# How to make the tutorial from pepper work on setlanguage and dialogue?

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

its my first time working with pepper and i am working locally on my computer with no connection to a real pepper. I am trying to follow the steps from http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/getting_started/helloworld_choregraphe_dialog.html#helloworld-choregraphe-dialog .
I am getting the error messages:

> [WARN ] behavior.box :getService:16
> _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_193854592:/Set Language_2: ALSpeechRecognition is not available, language setting
> cannot be applied to recognition.
> [ERROR] behavior.box
> :onInput_onSet:49
> _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_193854592:/Set Language_2: Language English could not be set for one or more
> services.

I tried following all steps in the tutorial and removed the german language which i originally intended to use. I have linked the modules correctly as well and would be really happy if you could tell me which mistake i need to fix in order to get it to work.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to define the projects language.

Click on properties (on the left side of choregraphe, next to the blue cube) and then, on the window that just opened, click the languages of your choice on the right column. Since you are here, don't forget either to give an application id.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the language has no effect on a virtual robot, because it as no TTS or ASR.
You can safely ignore the error or catch it, for instance by adding an `onError` output wired to the rest of your behavior.